# Access Docker Container from Google Cloud

Tags: docker, flask, google-cloud-platform, postgraphile

I'm running Docker containers on a Google Cloud instance using Docker Compose.
Here is the instance:

[image]

And here are the containers running:

```
$ docker-compose up -d db graphql api
Creating mobydq-db ... done
Creating mobydq-graphql ... done
Creating mobydq-api     ... done

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
05dae8c9340d        mobydq-api              "flask run --host=0.…"   5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:5434->5434/tcp             mobydq-api
30d6b7a6725e        graphile/postgraphile   "postgraphile -n 0.0…"   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5433->5433/tcp   mobydq-graphql
85c4e42e27fd        mobydq-db               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        5432/tcp                           mobydq-db
```

Two of these containers are supposed to be reachable at the following addresses:

- http://35.220.221.20:5434/mobydq/api/doc (Swagger doc generated with Falsk Restplus)
- http://35.220.221.20:5433/graphiql (GraphiQL doc generated by PostGraphile)

I also have firewall rules configured to ensure these ports are accessible from the internet:

[image]

Still, I'm unable to reach the two pages above from my browser. What am I missing?

Comment: sounds like a GCP firewall issue, probably the targets are not matched. you can try to run one of the services on port 80 for a test, the default policy is to allow traffic to that port for all instances.

Comment: as Uku Loskit said, you can try on port 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was installing my application in the Google Cloud Shell (1) instead of doing it on a Shell session connected to my VM instance (2).

[image]